# Will a hot liquid spilled on a hydrophobic surface transfer its heat to the surface?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, thermal-conductivity

This question also pertains to superhydrophobic and superomniphobic surfaces that may well have their 'phobic' properties through their topology or superficial layers.

Basically, I am curious to know if a phobic surface would be protected against damage from hot or boiling water or even steam because the beading of the water or any other liquid would reduce its contact time with the surface and therefore the time to conduct heat.

I imagine this would be an amazing attribute for a multitude of applications even in protective clothing. Thank you, any response is appreciated.

Comment: If you are thinking of a drop of liquid on superhydrophobic surface, then it is true that contact area would be less. But if you immerse the surface in liquid then that advantage is lost.